# ms unity and multiple constructors

Tags: c#, unity-container

im trying to get ms unity to inject an object into a constructor and am having problems due to the class having multiple constructors and the same number of parameters.  I know you can annotate the constructor but i dont want to do that.  How can i get unity to use the correct constructor

my constructors are like so :-

```
  public JobsHandler(ICentralRepositoryContainer context)
  public JobsHandler(ICentralRepositoryLifeTimehelper centralRepositoryLifeTimehelper)
```

and i was using some code i found :-

```
  uContainer.RegisterType<ICentralRepositoryContainer, Entities>().Configure<InjectedMembers>().
            ConfigureInjectionFor<JobsHandler>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

but in getting a

> The type CentralRepository.BusinessLogic.JobsHandler does not have a
>   constructor that takes the parameters ()

Im guess this is because i havent specified the parameters in the injectionconstructor object.  Am i doing this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will want to resolve the ICentralRepositoryContainer and use it in the InjectionConstructor

```
uContainer.RegisterType<ICentralRepositoryContainer, Entities>().Configure<InjectedMembers>().ConfigureInjectionFor<JobsHandler>(
  new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ICentralRepositoryContainer)));
```

Or register the jobs handler while specifying the constructor.

```
uContainer.RegisterType<ICentralRepositoryContainer, Entities>();
uContainer.RegisterType<JobsHandler>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(ICentralRepositoryContainer))));
```

See this link for a more complete example of the above:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650036.aspx

Comment: that doesnt work.  ConfigureInjectionFor is not a member of the container

Comment: My apologies. I meant using the RegisterType method. I have ammended the above and added an example using your original method.
P.S. I am not 100% sure if this will work as I cannot verify it currently. But I think this is roughly what you need to do.